# "Some required components are missing"--cannot connect from Linux to Windows w/Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS (same core as Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), a Debian Linux Distro, and need to be able to connect *from here* **to** a *Windows Machine* using the `Chrome Remote Desktop` tool. I have the server side of it working on the Windows Machine, and can log in to it from my Android phone, but I am unable to log in from Xubuntu.

I get this error when I try: "Some required components are missing. Please go to chrome://plugins and make sure Native Client is enabled." (see screenshot below).

[image]

When I go to chrome://plugins, however, I get the following:

[image]

That's it! There is no "Native Client" plugin to enable. How do I fix this error so I can log in to the Windows computer from the Linux computer using Chrome Remote Desktop?

Note: I installed the Chromium browser into Xubuntu using `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`.

---

Stack Exchange Note: this question was originally posted on [StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894586/some-required-components-are-missing-cannot-connect-from-linux-to-windows-w-c), but was "put on hold" by admins since it was more of a "[Super User](https://superuser.com/)" or "[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)" type question. Therefore, I have moved the question to here. Meanwhile, throughout this process, I also discovered the answer to my own question and hence am answering it myself to help others too.

Happy Remote Desktop-ing
~Gabriel
[www.ElectricRCAircraftGuy.com](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the answer to my question:

Despite having used Linux Ubuntu, Xubuntu, and Mint for the last 4 years or so, I never knew they can run actual Google Chrome, instead of just Chromium. The solution lies in simply installing the actual Google Chrome. So here's the answer:

1. Download Google Chrome for Linux Ubuntu/Xubuntu: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/. My download was called `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
2. Install it. You *may* be able to do this simply by double-clicking the installation file and following the installer. When I tried that, however, it failed for some reason, so I had to do it via the terminal:

   - `sudo chmod +x google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` <--I'm not sure if this command is necessary, but I did it anyway.
   - `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`. This worked for me! It only took a few seconds to install Google Chrome. Note that I now have both Chromium *and* Google Chrome installed at the same time with no conflicts. They work fine together, as they are separate programs.
3. Now, the [Chrome Remote Desktop app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) works just fine for me, and I no longer get the error (mentioned above in my question) like I did when I tried it with just Chromium installed. I am able now to remote-connect from Linux Xubuntu 16.04 to Windows 8.1 (which also has Google Chrome Remote Desktop installed and configured as a host/server) just fine! Finally, an easy way to connect from Linux to Windows, not just the other way around.

**General Remote Desktop connection recommendations:**

- For remote connections **from Windows to Linux** I recommend using Windows' built-in `Remote Desktop Connection` client on Windows, and the `xrdp` server on Linux. For terminal-only logins, I use [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) on Windows to SSH into the Linux machine.
- For remote desktop connections **from Linux to Linux** I recommend using [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) as the client on Linux, and `xrdp` as the server on Linux. For terminal-only logins, I still like using [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) as the client on Linux (`sudo apt-get install putty`) to SSH from one Linux machine into another.
- For remote desktop connections **from Linux to Windows, OR Windows to Windows** I recommend using [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) and the [Chrome Remote Desktop App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) on both the Linux *and* the Windows system, as described in my answer above.

Cheers,
~Gabriel
[www.ElectricRCAircraftGuy.com](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem. It was very frustrating as every single answer I found was similar to the above, "install the official Chrome browser".

Well I installed the official Chrome browser, and even the bleeding edge Chrome browser but kept getting the same error as above when connecting to my Windows computers with Chrome Remote Desktop. As noted, I could also connect successfully with Android.

I finally found a solution from this URL https://www.reddit.com/r/GalliumOS/comments/41fbvv/chrome_remote_desktop/

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb python-psutil
```

Once I installed those, chrome remote desktop finally worked properly.

I hope this helps others.

Comment: So are you using the official Chrome Browser now, or Chromium, with your fix?

Comment: This also solved the problem for me, going between 2 Ubuntu machines.